# gradle: set sonarRunner settings for projects applying specific plugin

Tags: android, gradle, sonarqube, sonar-runner

We use a company-wide gradle configuration which is applied to all our gradle projects.

Projects using this config might apply different types of plugins (specificially the plugins `java` or `android` & `android-library`). In order to get the `sonarRunner` plugin to automatically check the android projects, additional properties have to be applied which are not available for java projects.

Now to the question: How can additional sonarRunner (or other) properties be applied only to projects applying a specific (in this case "android" or "android-library") plugin?

What I have tried so far, but does not work as the `AndroidPlugin` property is not know in the preparation phase:

```
plugins.withType(AndroidPlugin) {
    sonarRunner {
        sonarProperties {
            property "sonar.profile", "Android"      
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the code is missing an import for the `AndroidPlugin` class. Alternatively, `plugins.withId("android")` can be used for current gradle versions or `afterEvaluate { if (plugins.hasPlugin("android")) { ... } }` for gradle 1.12 and earlier.

Comment: Hi, I can not apply the `android` plugin in the parent config as it is mutual exclusive with the `java` plugin. How can i check all subprojects for the existence of a specific plugin (howto use your second advice)?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Is this a new question?

Comment: The `android` plugin supplies the `AndroidPlugin` class. I can not load the `android` plugin in the company gradle script at it interferes with the `java` plugin. The question remains the same: how can I check for sub-projects which apply a distinct plugin (`android`) withouth the plugin being present at the Initialization phase?

Comment: You cannot apply both plugins to the same project, but you should nevertheless be able to declare the Android plugin dependency in the company Gradle script (although you may not want to). However you don't have to - just use `plugins.withId("android")` instead of `plugins.withType(AndroidPlugin)`.

Comment: Thanks, now I got it, but unfortunately the `withId` method is not known: `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.withId() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, ...`

Comment: `withId` only exists in recent Gradle versions. In older versions, you could perhaps use `afterEvaluate { if (plugins.hasPlugin("android")) { ... } }`.